# dojo.io.iframe.send not working with IE v10?

Tags: file, internet-explorer, iframe, download

I've been using dojo v1.7 lately to upload/download a file. I have deployed a servlet class inside of websphere app server to handle request/response traffic. However, I ran into a problem downloading a file via iframe.send + servlet. Well, with FF/Chrome, it works, but with IE v10 it doesn't. It seems like an instance of the servlet class never invoked. I do have logging implemented within doGet method to log what is transmitted. Nothing is recorded when I initiate http request via IE 10. I'd appreciate your input on this.

```
iframe.send({ 
    method: "GET",
    content: {
         name: "base64_string_value"
    },
    url: "/myServlet"
}).then(function(data) {}, function(err) {});
```

[update]
After wrapping input tag by form tag and specifying form attribute within send method, request was processed by the servlet however, from a browser side, I expected a dialog box asking users to either open or save, but it didn't happen. Rather I got "This page can't be displayed." in a browser.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="submit" value="Download"></input>
</form>

iframe.send({ .... form: "myForm" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to apologize for not being truthful in the question. The data I was trying to submit was not just a file name (I corrected contents of my question), but base64 string value rather large. I thought regardless of the data size, the servlet would return a file object after reading the contents (base64) of requested file. After switching submitting form from Get to POST, and do proper engineer in the servlet class (implemented doPost and discarded doGet), downloading a file from a browser worked just fine both in IE and Chrome.